# Convert time range to a text value

Tags: excel, vba, formula-editor

I have a table in excel that has a column with times in it hh:mm:ss
I want to convert it so that anything from:
08:00:00 to 17:59:59 is the text value D
18:00:00 to 23:59:59 is the text value E
00:00:00 to 07:59:59 is the text value N

I am having issues doing this and wondered if you could help?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It may be easier for you to do it without VBA. Look into the `=IF` function in Excel.

Comment: You need to use a nested `If` statement. Read about it [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_nested.php). Your formula will be something like `=IF(AND(A1>=TIMEVALUE("08:00:00"),A1<TIMEVALUE("18:00:00"), ...`

Comment: Tony solved it below. Tony you legend. I was trying this function but could not work it out.

Comment: Likewise if I am trying to apply this to a number sequence that requires more than 3 inputs can I still us the IF function? I also need to convert age ranges to text

Comment: @Medberry, sure, just remember to balance your parenthesis.  Check out the Switch function too if your result set is finite enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need VBA.  Assuming your time value is in A2, Try this:

```
 =IF(HOUR(A2)>=18,"E",IF(HOUR(A2)>=8,"D","N"))
```

Comment: Tony thanks, that works great. Can I use it for more than 3 values. For example I have a column that has ages in it.

Comment: <0.1 Neonate
<1 Infant
<5 Toddler
<16 Child
<80 Adult
>80 Elderly

Comment: @Medberry... `=IF(A2>=80,"Elderly",IF(A2>=16,"Adult",IF(A2>=5,"Child",IF(A2>=1,"Toddler",IF(A2>=0.1,"Infant","Neonate")))))`

Comment: Tony, thanks. I worked it out and we came up with the same values. Thanks so much for your help.